# After Downloading with wget, Cecksums Hashes are different with original file. Is re-downloading the only way to repair?

Tags: data-recovery, downloads, wget, checksums

It was a **tar.gz** archive (*eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz*) and was downloaded 100% due to wget-log.

Is there any way to recover this file without re-downloading? The size of local file is 160.2 MB that seems larger than actual size (152.82 MB).
Beside Checksums difference, This is file check which returns `data`:

```
$ file eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
eclipse-java-luna-SR1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz: data
```

I wonder if there's a way like what is done in `Torrent` (Chunk download and checksums for each chunk) for `wget`. Or even using some parameters in the `wget` command, to avoid the same problem in future.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. `wget` has no partial checksumming (it just has a simple restart option in case of a lost connection midway).

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, Yes I'm familiar with the `-c` flag and had used it on this particular download too, But as you said it's just a simple restart and couldn't prevent integrity defection. (Or maybe it was the reason of the problem itself? :D )